# Electronic differential

Tags: differential

I am an under graduate in Electrical engineering and I'm doing a project on electric vehicle.
I learned that Tesla Model S use two separate motors for two wheels. Does that mean it uses an electronic differential?
I intend to use an electronic differential for my project.
My question is if that is feasible due to technical and safety reasons?
Will I have to abandon my project??

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Teslas with one motor per wheel do not use a differential at all, such as the Roadster v2 (which has a motor for each rear wheel) but for those that have one motor per axle, they use a fairly normal open differential. Yes, it is electronic rather than a limited slip diff, but this is not because it is an EV - it's just relatively common these days.

So yes, it is feasible.

Comment: An electronic differential is more of a ‘logical’ device rather than a physical component - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_differential.  Presumably the Tesla will have such logic built into its drive system.

Comment: Yes, it's through braking at each wheel

Comment: I don’t think it involves braking, it just alters the power to each motor to give equal torque when cornering.

Comment: @HandyHowie Hmmm - I thought that was only for those with one motor per wheel.

Comment: @HandyHowie making a motor into a generator is known as braking...

Comment: So it is possible to use one motor per wheel controlled by an electronic differential based on a computer program that adjusts the speed of each wheel when turning a curve.?

Comment: @SolarMike keeping constant torque across wheels can’t involve braking.  Have you read the Wikipedia article?

Comment: @ASWINVENU Yes, as described in the wikipedia article I attached.

Comment: @HandyHowie who said constant torque? - not what I said at all. Consider differential torque... aka braking one wheel / motor or aka supplying less power to one motor from the controller.

Comment: @SolarMike The whole point in a differential is that it applies the same torque to both wheels while allowing them to turn at different speeds, which is what the OP is talking about.  When cornering, you would not apply braking to one wheel while powering the other.

Comment: @HandyHowie obviously you have not seen abs or torque control systems in action then or you don’t know how they work.

Comment: @SolarMike Please enlighten me.